When do native speakers say I would, she would,... or I had, she had, ... instead of I'd, She'd in everyday speech?
I find it really challenging to master contractions in speaking when it comes to "had" and "would".
As far as I know, the "non-contracted" forms are usually used in formal speech. What about in everyday speech? When can I use them without sounding overly and unnecessarily formal? Besides, is it bad to sound formal in everyday conversations?

Your idea that non-contracted forms are used in formal speech is mistaken. When speaking, unless you are using slang, contracted or non-contracted forms depend on what the speaker wants to say.  But it does not boil down to formality/informality.

Thanks. I see what you mean.

Another answer has already noted that you might expand the contraction if you want to emphasize one of the words in it individually. And you're right that you'd want to avoid it in the most formal writing—e.g. I would use contractions in a business letter or an opinion essay in a newspaper, but I find that I (unconsciously) avoided them in my dissertation paper.
Another reason I can think of is that you might expand the contraction simply to increase the overall emphasis. Contractions "relax" the tone; removing them makes it not only more formal but more emphatic. If you have to repeat yourself and are getting frustrated, you might expand the contraction:

"Where'd you go just now, Junior? I was looking for you."
"Mommy! Mommy! I'm hungry! I want an ice cream cone!"
"Junior, you didn't answer me: Where did you go?"

As I tried to come up with examples just now, I feel like we might be more inclined to expand the contraction the longer or more difficult to pronounce it is. A short, easy contraction like "it's" might survive even furious intensity ("I SAID it's FINE!!"), though you might expand it if you've gotten to the point that you're spacing your words out ("Listen very closely. That... is... not... okay!"). I have a very hard time imagining "can't" being expanded to "can not" in all but the most icy formality or raging fury. But "what'd," "where'd," and "why'd" seem much more eager to expand. "What'd" in particular, with its double consonant, is hard to say, and comes out sounding pretty much the same as "what did" anyway."
Finally, the expanded form can be easier to understand. If you used a contraction and someone failed to understand you, you might expand it, or you might leave them out when talking to small children, the hard of hearing, or non-fluent speakers.


Is it bad to sound formal in everyday conversations?

My general answer is "no." My spoken language is often rather academic, because I feel no shame in being a "geek," and use words like "whereas" in actual conversation. More importantly, formal forms are often clear, and when learning a language, it's better to be clearly understood and thought a bit "stiff" than to be misunderstood in an attempt to be "cool." I would always encourage learners to learn standard forms first, and adopt slang or figures of speech only as you hear them used around you.
But it is worth getting accustomed to contractions and using them comfortably, because yes, it can make you seem stiff or stilted to always avoid them, and sometimes this can cause the reader to perceive a tone that you don't intend.
On the TV show Star Trek: The Next Generation there's a humanoid robot character named Data. His artificial intelligence is human-like, and one episode even argues that he should be considered "a person" with full rights, but a running theme is his Pinocchio-like desire to be "more human," and his frequent failure to read social cues and adjust his tone to the occasion. One stylistic gimmick in the development of his character is that he doesn't use contractions. Regardless of the fictional explanations for this, it has the narrative effect of heightening his "non-humanness" and calling attention to his failure to fit in with the rest of the crew.
Avoiding contractions can make you "sound like Data." Worse, it might be mistaken for heightened emphasis or anger. And a mismatch in tone can be heightened depending on the tone that's expected for the situation. If I got a printed invitation in the mail inviting me to a dinner party, then I would think nothing of formal language. If, instead, my close friend invites me to come over for burgers and beer, and they email:

You are invited to my house. We will have burgers and beer...

... Then I might think to myself, "Geez, why so formal? You're not addressing the board of shareholders here, it's just a get-together." This is drawn from real life, in fact; I have a friend who communicates this way, and I've come to expect it from them and know it's just how they write. But at the worst, if I were new to the friendship, I might worry that I had offended them and they were angry with me. This might be even more likely if the communication were by text message!

All answers here are helpful but thank you for such a detailed answer.

You don't even address the contracted form as part of normal speech. formal speech as used by the OP is a misnomer.

@Lambie Quite true. But maybe it got lost in the long-windedness, but I meant for the whole last section to amount to "Contractions are standard in normal conversational speech, and avoiding them can be odd or worse." Mind you, I could imagine very (truly) formal occasions of speaking in which one might do without them, like when giving a speech before the U.N. Were I in such a position I might still choose to use them, since I hold that simplicity and clarity are virtues... but maybe not quite as many as around my buddies, burgers, and beers.

@AndyBonner Giving a speech is not included in this description. It would have to be "in a formal speech".

The non-contracted forms are usually only used in speech when it is necessary to put a stress on one or other of the two words:

I would like to see that film, even if you don't.
I would like to go with you, but I have a meeting at 5pm.


I can emphasise the I in I'd - it's quite common.

Brits know about Mandy Rice-Davies' famous answer in court, to a lawyer's question, now a British political phrase and aphorism that is commonly used as a retort to a self-interested denial.

In my experience, the contracted forms are informal and the uncontracted forms are neutral, neither formal nor informal. In certain kinds of writing you would avoid the contracted form but the uncontracted form can always be used.

I would walk right up to him and kick him in the shin, if I were you. He shouldn't have backed out of the prom at the last minute like that. He can have his appendix out tomorrow.


So in conditional sentence type 2, we shouldn't write the contracted form "I'd"? Besides, regarding formality, are you talking about writing only or both writing and speaking?

I don't want to make too broad a statement, speech vs writing.  If you want to have a neutral tone or a formal tone in something you're writing or in a talk you're delivering, best to avoid the contracted forms.  You have to judge what tone is appropriate for your subject matter and your audience. Informality can be a desirable tone.

Contracted forms are standard in speech. Formality has little to do with it.

@Lambie  Little to do with what?  You may know what you have in mind. I don't.  And I don't know what "standard in speech" means.  Speech has a range of registers.

Formality has little to do with contracted versus non-contracted speech.

@Lambie I disagree. Can you show some formal speech, e.g. a legal ruling, that uses contractionss like "can't" and "won't" or "he'd" or "they'd" or "shouldn't"?

Well, it depends on what you mean by speech. I'm referring to speech as actual talking. Look at the OP's first sentence. These contractions she is having difficulty with is about that. Then, she segues into what she has heard about non-contracted forms. I guess she means written forms.

What do you mean by formal speech??
I would go if I could, wouldn't you?
I wouldn't go even if I could, would you?
Those examples are typical speech. I see no way to make them "more formal".
I had left my cup on the table before you arrived, hadn't I?
I hadn't left my cup on the table before you arrived, had I?
What this article says about formal speech is just not accurate: formal speech
Reading that article would lead one to believe that tags on utterances at dinner parties is "wrong". Question tags are not "informal speech" necessarily. And I would use the term formal language rather than formal speech, which to me, in conversation or an interview would mean: no slang but it wouldn't mean no colloquial language.
It is not true that "native speakers" always use "I would" or "I had" instead of I'd [verb] or I'd [verb]. That is a gross generalization that does not reflect the real world.

She'd leave early if she could. For example.
He'd left early but she didn't realize it until later.

Watch a few streaming movies in AmE (or even BrE) and you will see.

This is part of why I often substitute "academic" for "formal." There are some expectations of style and usage for school essays, different ones for business memos and speeches to the board, and others for everyday conversation. Often you see people get hold of "formal" as a notion and try to use the school-essay standards in their business emails because they want to be "professional," and come off as awkward or standoffish.

@AndyBonner My point is about speech (speaking). speech goes to speaking, language doesn't necessarily. There is formal and informal language and there is formal and informal speech. Academic is a separate category and I was looking to disabuse the OP of inaccurate descriptions and notions.
